# making a custom list that scrolls horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, list, scroll

I just started with WPF and I have no idea how I would go about making a scrollable list. I want to be able to put a custom object inside of it and then scroll sideways.

Is there anyone that may have any idea where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making a `ListBox` scroll Horizontally is pretty simple:

```xml
<ListBox Margin="20">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <!-- If you need Virtualization then check up on that topic accordingly and you'd need to switch the following StackPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel -->
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something A" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something B" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something C" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something D" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something E" />
  <ListBoxItem Content="Something F" />
</ListBox>
```

As for the custom object part, Try to firstly go through some basic examples of working with a `ListBox` control say like [These](http://wpftutorial.net/ListBox.html).

You'd then pretty much just have your collection of custom objects Bound to the `ListBox` via it's `ItemSource` and then have `DataTemplate`'s defined in xaml that would help visualise your custom objects.

Pretty much every techy word in that^^ statement(`Binding`, `ItemSource`, `DataTemplate`) you'd want to understand first and you can find extensive help with each by just searching, aint something new.

Comment: In most cases, you should use `VirtualizingStackPanel` with the same orientation instead of `StackPanel` as the `ItemPanelTemplate`.

Comment: @SimonBelanger That's upto the requirements in the UI. The concept of `Orientation` via an `ItemsPanelTemplate` is what I'm trying to convey and not the actual control. I'll add it as comment in xaml nonetheless

Comment: I agree. I realised it may have sounded like it, but I wasn't disagreeing with you, only adding to your answer. ;)